# how to pass dynamic values to the page-objects when using xpath or css

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have to pass dynamic values to check the text_field values exists or not. How can we do that by using Page-object in class.

Below i should pass inspect value dynamically. I am using cucumber example tables to provide value for inspect.

### Code:

```
class VerifyDetailsPage
include PageObject
include CommonPage

in_iframe(:index => 1) do |frame|
    text_field(:reverse_check, xpath: "//input[@value='#{inspect}']", frame: frame)
end

def reverse_route
     if reverse_check_element.exists?
        soon...
     else
        ...
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the accessors methods being created when the class is evaluated, you cannot use the accessors for elements you need to dynmically locate. For more details, you can see the feature request - [Issue 203](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/203).

An alternative approach is to use the page object's regular locator methods. For example, you could create a `reverse_check_element` method to get the input field for a given value:

```
class VerifyDetailsPage
  include PageObject

  def reverse_check_element(inspect)
    platform.in_iframe(:index => 1) do |frame|
      text_field_element(xpath: "//input[@value='#{inspect}']", :frame => frame)
    end
  end
end
```

The `reverse_route` method could call the `reverse_check_element` method with the desired value:

```
def reverse_route(inspect)
  if reverse_check_element(inspect).exists?
    # soon...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```